# Codeigniter: Redirect() refresh/location parameter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

Can anyone explain the specific difference between using the 'location' and 'refresh' parameters for the redirect() function.  Is it ONLY for when Windows misbehaves that you use 'refresh' or does it actually serve a more important purpose?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985537/what-are-differences-between-location-and-refresh-in-codeginiter-redirect-functi

Comment: thank you..i searched so much and didnt come across that answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CodeIgniter's `redirect` function (located in [`system/helpers/url_helper.php`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/url_helper.php#L531)) allows you to send HTTP headers using PHP's [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

The **[location](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)** header instructs a web browser to load a web page and is sent with a *3xx* HTTP status code. For example: *301* - moved temporarily or *302* - moved permanently (CodeIgniter's default).

> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient
>   to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the request
>   or identification of a new resource.

**[Refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header)** is actually a proprietary extension that was created by Netscape. It isn't part of the [official standards](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), but most web browsers have adopted it and support it.

---

There are several reasons why you might want to use one or the other - `location` should be supported by all browsers that comply to the standards but `refresh` may not. `refresh` could ['break' the back button](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback) of the browser (while `location` won't) and may have [performance issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/meta-refresh-causes-additional-http-requests.aspx). `location` sends a reason for the redirect, in a HTTP code, but `refresh` doesn't; it only instructs the browser to refresh a specified page.